# Compilation error installing R package glmnet

Tags: r

I'm having trouble installing glmnet on my Linux desktop. Below is the error I get when I run

```
R CMD INSTALL -d glmnet_4.0-2.tar.gz
```

I first tried `install.packages("glmnet")` with the same results. Ran `R CMD INSTALL` with `-d` hoping for some additional debug info.

```
processing ‘glmnet_4.0-2.tar.gz’
a file
* installing to library ‘/home/sconoor/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
* build_help_types=html
* DBG: 'R CMD INSTALL' now doing do_install()
* created lock directory ‘/home/sconoor/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/00LOCK-glmnet’
* installing *source* package ‘glmnet’ ...
** package ‘glmnet’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
about to run R CMD SHLIB -o glmnet.so glmnet5dpclean.f glmnet_init.c pb.c wls.f
77  -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules  -c glmnet5dpclean.f -o glmnet5dpclean.o
make: 77: Command not found
make: *** [glmnet5dpclean.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘glmnet’
* removing ‘/home/sconoor/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/glmnet’
```

For some reason `R CMD INSTALL` is substituting `77` where I would expect `gfortran` at the compilation step. I have searched for others that may have encountered this issue and haven't found any. I am at a loss as to how to fix this. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Here is the R version info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.utf8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.utf8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.utf8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.utf8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.utf8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C              LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.utf8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.0
```

System info:

```
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)
Release:        7.8.2003
Codename:       Core
```

and gcc version

```
gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.9.2
```

Comment: do you have a weird `Makevars` file somewhere, e.g. in `~/.R/Makevars` ?

Comment: I don't think it's particular to the `glmnet` package (https://github.com/cran/glmnet), as it doesn't have a Makefile or Makevars file at all. I @BenBolker might be onto something.

Comment: it's also conceivable that you could be picking up strange environment variables.  What do you get from (in the shell) `R CMD config FC` (Ref: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Using-Makevars) ?

Comment: @BenBolker thank you for the pointer. You are exactly right. The output of `R CMD config FC` is `77`.  The same command on my Mac laptop returns `gfortran`. I'm not sure how I have the compiler set to `77` on my desktop. I did upgrade gcc from 4.8 to 4.9 about a month ago to get Stan to install. Not sure if something unintended happened then.

Comment: the weird value only shows you that it's going wrong *somewhere*. Have you looked at `~/.R/Makevars` yet?

Comment: @BenBolker Here are the contents of `~/.R/Makevars - ```CXX_STD = CXX14
CXX14 = g++ -std=c++1y
CXX14FLAGS = -O3 -fPIC -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function -DBOOST_PHOENIX_NO_VARIADIC_EXPRESSION
F77 = /usr/bin/gfortran
FC = $F77
FLIBS = -L/usr/bin/gfortran```  I can confirm that `/usr/bin/gfortran` exists.

Comment: @BenBolker Thank you so much for providing the direction I needed in resolving this. Looking at the contents of Makevars I realized the error in definition of `FC`.  Changed it to `$(F77)` and it now works. I was able to install glmnet. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As identified by @BenBolker the problem was a mistake in the ~/.R/Makevars file. I recall creating the Makevars file with a snippet copied from an SO answer on compiling StanHeaders with support for C++14. I missed the error in the definition of the make variable for the path to the fortran compiler.